# How to get all the fields from my model in Loopback 4

Tags: loopback

I have a MongoDB Collection with more then 400 fields, How can i get all the fields without defining each of them in the model. Right now i am only getting the fields that i have defined in the model. I have tried passing no arguments in the filter but still getting only the defined fields.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

*Disclaimer: I am a maintainer of LoopBack 4. The text below is cross-posted from our documentation in https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Model.html#using-the-juggler-bridge, see also my [pull request #1745](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/pull/1475) that introduced strict mode.*

Models are defined primarily by their TypeScript class. By default, classes forbid additional properties that are not specified in the type definition. The persistence layer respects this constraint and configures underlying PersistedModel classes to enforce strict mode.

To create a model that allows both well-defined but also arbitrary extra properties, you need to disable strict mode in model settings and tell TypeScript to allow arbitrary additional properties to be set on model instances.

```
@model({settings: {strict: false}})
class MyFlexibleModel extends Entity {
  @property({id: true})
  id: number;

  // Define well-known properties here

  // Add an indexer property to allow additional data
  [prop: string]: any;
}
```